# JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList() returns empty array

Tags: java, jpcap

I have an example of a traffic sniffer and it uses JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList() . The problem is that this method returns an empty array, although it seems it shouldn't. Could it be that i haven't installed jpcap 100% correct? What could be wrong?
Also, i have found jpcap documentation at jpcap.sourceforge.net/javadoc/ , but there is none JpcapCaptor at all. Where can i get the rest of the jpcap documentation?

I use Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: run JDE as administrator if using Windows.
For additional documentation look at
http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfuji...doc/index.html

The link is dead, but you can find it in the archives